# Insert bigquery job table not found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am trying to run an asynchronous query. When I submit it to Bigquery it answers me that the table does not exist (status is "DONE"). What is wrong?

```
jobData = {'configuration': {'query': {'query': query, 'createDisposition': 'CREATE_NEVER'}}}
logger.info('jobdata: %s', jobData)
insertResponse = self.service.jobs().insert(projectId = PROJECT_ID, body = jobData).execute()
if 'errorResult' in str(insertResponse):
    logger.error('query insert failed: %s', insertResponse)
```

This worked a few weeks back but no more. The error I get seems to indicate that the table cannot be found (or is it some kind of temporary table and all is well?)

```
jobdata: {'configuration': {'query': {'createDisposition': 'CREATE_NEVER', 'query': 'SELECT TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(timestamp) AS timestamp, location, branch, platform, description, original, metrics.group, metrics.id, metrics.name, metrics.value, DATE(timestamp) AS date FROM [mm.autotest] WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), timestamp) < 14'}}}

query insert failed: {u'status': {u'state': u'DONE', u'errors': [{u'reason': u'notFound', u'message': u'Not found: Table ava-backend:_24bc4b39cef74439ece7e6f9a41399c21fccacd8.anonev_c7HQskNXMdaxCBDXdnAtOzlSJ6M'}], u'errorResult': {u'reason': u'notFound', u'message': u'Not found: Table ava-backend:_24bc4b39cef74439ece7e6f9a41399c21fccacd8.anonev_c7HQskNXMdaxCBDXdnAtOzlSJ6M'}}, u'kind': u'bigquery#job', u'statistics': {u'endTime': u'1390899670652', u'creationTime': u'1390899670344', u'startTime': u'1390899670652'}, u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'ava-backend', u'jobId': u'job_EowCD-kiOirnlyRAQjFJNFoRFUY'}, u'etag': u'"11dTZYgUnUwbk8emYQU9mVRTTLs/0mRkexpB4dgaqONWphRujyRJhqM"', u'configuration': {u'query': {u'createDisposition': u'CREATE_NEVER', u'query': u'SELECT TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(timestamp) AS timestamp, location, branch, platform, description, original, metrics.group, metrics.id, metrics.name, metrics.value, DATE(timestamp) AS date FROM [mm.autotest] WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), timestamp) < 14'}}, u'id': u'ava-backend:job_EowCD-kiOirnlyRAQjFJNFoRFUY', u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/ava-backend/jobs/job_EowCD-kiOirnlyRAQjFJNFoRFUY'}
```

The query works fine in Bigquery web interface and if run synchronously with 'query' instead of 'insert'

Could it possibly be an authentication issue? When I run the query with "query" it works but I get a warning message:

```
Checking for id_token.
id_token verification failed: Can't parse header: '\xc9\xad\xbd'
Checking for oauth token.
Client ID is not allowed: 173893847593-pdkumgr5bhobh3tv6qhqqfvel2tvnns0.apps.googleusercontent.com
URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/ava-backend/queries?alt=json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `'createDisposition': 'CREATE_NEVER'`. This tells BigQuery that you never want to create a table for the query results. So it fails when the query result table doesn't exist. If you remove that create disposition, it should work.

Comment: Yes thx @Jordan Tigani I tried removing the create disposition and then it works. However as I read the documentation it is recommended that it should be used or do I read it backwards somehow?

(https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#asyncqueries)

`Ensuring cached query results: 

If you use the jobs.insert() function to run a query, you can ensure that the job returns a query result from the cache, if it exists, by setting the createDisposition property of the job configuration to CREATE_NEVER.`

Comment: Yes, this means that your query will _only_ succeed if the query is already cached. If you run with the normal create disposition, your query will be satisfied from the cache if possible.